# android kernel source code compilation error

Tags: android, compilation, kernel

I need to customize the kernel of android to run on my Nexus S.

So I download the kernel with branch name "remotes/origin/android-samsung-2.6.35-gingerbread"

I tried to follow the instruction here http://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html to build the kernel. To do this, I need the cross compile tool.In my target android source code version android-2.3.5_r1, there is no such tool(no prebuilts/ folder). So I downloaded the version 4.1.2 and set up the tool as path prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin .
Then I tried to build my kernel, but I got the following error:

```
[root@localhost samsung]# make 
scripts/kconfig/conf -s arch/arm/Kconfig
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: `include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      drivers/gpu/pvr/osfunc.o
In file included from drivers/gpu/pvr/osfunc.c:39:0:
include/linux/pagemap.h: In function 'fault_in_pages_readable':
include/linux/pagemap.h:415:16: error: variable 'c' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
drivers/gpu/pvr/osfunc.c: In function 'OSAccessOK':
drivers/gpu/pvr/osfunc.c:2144:13: error: variable 'linuxType' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

make[3]: *** [drivers/gpu/pvr/osfunc.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [drivers/gpu/pvr] Error 2
make[1]: *** [drivers/gpu] Error 2
make: *** [drivers] Error 2
```

Should I just disable the "all warnings being treated as errors" to solve it? Or maybe I need a better toolchain?

PS: The tool chain of the master branch and branch 4.2 can not be used by me. Because it looks like they are made for a 64-bit OS while my linux is 32-bit

Comment: Did you do the other steps before issuing 'make'?

Comment: @PeterL. Sure. From change ARCH to make herring_defconfig

Comment: It has been over a year since I've built the Android tree, but seem to remember that there were more steps.  See the link (from where you pointed to in your post) that says 'Initializing the Build Environment'.  The first build should take a few hours.  It is best (that is how I found it) to build everything once, then go in and just rebuild the kernel when you need to.  Also, you should do your initial build from the top of the Android tree.

Comment: @PeterL. Great.It works. After building the AOSP, some toolchains will be automatically added to the PATH. The reason why I want to build kernel first is that I want to add the built kernel binary into AOSP and after that do an AOSP build. So I think I should first build AOSP, then build kernel and last build AOSP again with new built kernel.

Comment: That's what we used to always have to do.  Build everything first unchanged, then modify what you need to change in the kernel and rebuild it.  The second build of only the changed code will go much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the path of ARCH=ARM and TOOLCHAIN pointing to the toolchain in \prebuilts folder?

```
make ARCH=ARM TOOLCHAIN=\<homeofAOSP>\prebuilt\.. herring_defconfig
```

`make clean` before you do the `make`